# Getting error Invalid block tag on line 80: 'NOUN_LIST|count_ordered', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-custom-tags

I created a custom tag and getting error as :

---

Request Method:     GET

Request URL:    ""

Django Version:     2.2.1

Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError

Exception Value:    Invalid block tag on line 80: ''NOUN_LIST|count_ordered'', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

---

My Project Structure is :

[image: Project Structure]

---

custom_tag.py :

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
@register.simple_tag
def count_ordered(value):
    dict = sorted(value, key=lambda val:len(val.list),reverse=True)
    return dict
```

---

I am calling this tag as :

```
{% load custom_tag %}
{% NOUN_LIST|count_ordered as list %}
{{ list }}
```

---

Comment: after adding new templatetag you need to stop and start the `python manage.py runserver` command again.

Comment: I tried, but not worked.

Comment: what is the response when use like, `{% count_ordered NOUN_LIST %}`

Comment: will you post the `NOUN_LIST`. also you must not use `dict` as variable because it is a built in command

Comment: this worked  `{% count_ordered NOUN_LIST %}`
Thankyou @suhailvs